# How to make the external screens the defaults for open applications?

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, cinnamon, external-monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 with Cinnnamon 4.4.8. I'm using two external screens together with my laptop screen (one of the externals is configured as primary). I use the laptop screen for a single application (slack) and the two external screens for all other usages. But every time I disconnect and then reconnect to the external screens, all applications are on my laptop's screen and I need to drag them back.
Any way to make this easier (set the primary as the default screen for running applications on connection or something?). A way to move apps between screens using the keyboard is also welcome.
Thanks